# Get total records in fnClick: (datatables.net)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have this code, i would get the total number of records, how i can do?
I tried to ask in datatables.net forum but noone helped me...

```
   tableTools: {
     "sSwfPath": window.STATIC_BASE + cripts/datatable/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
      "aButtons": [ "pdf", "csv",
      "print",
      {   "sExtends": "text",
          "sButtonText": "TotalRecords",
          "fnClick": function () {
           var record_count = this.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
           alert(record_count);
           }
      }
      ]
    }
```

If I try to launch an alert with a normal string (ex. "hello world") it work, so the problem is the request of total records...

Thank you to all

Comment: (Since you should have edited this post instead of creating an answer,) Do you have a line for this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your scope is wrong : `this`.

Try :

```
var oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({

//...

tableTools: {
     "sSwfPath": "window.STATIC_BASE + cripts/datatable/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
      "aButtons": [ "pdf", "csv",
      "print",
      {   "sExtends": "text",
          "sButtonText": "TotalRecords",
          "fnClick": function () {
           var record_count = oTable.fnSettings().fnRecordsTotal();
           alert(record_count);
           }
      }
      ]
    }

//...

});
```

**EDIT:** After your answer, could you try :

`var oTable = $(self.table).dataTable();` instead of `var oTable = self.table;`

Comment: Thank you so much! .dataTable() is the solution! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to attain this using dataTables 1.10.1?